# Mysql query for Ask-Answer-Comment database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a database structure for Question/Answer/Comment like stachexchange projects, the database schema can be three columns connected with `FK`s. This seems to be ideal, but I wonder what is the most efficient query to retrieve the data for a question. Answers will be simply retrieved and listed by a WHERE clause of the question_id.

My question is how to list comments nested under its corresponding answer? I am dealing with the PHP while loop to list answers and sub-lists of comments.

A very basic structure in my mind. A purpose of my question is to find idea database structure too; thus, this is merely a suggestion.

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
question_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (question_id);

CREATE TABLE answers (
answer_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
question_id int(11) REFERENCES questions(question_id),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (answer_id);

CREATE TABLE comments (
coment_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
question_id int(11) REFERENCES questions(question_id),
answer_id int(11) REFERENCES answers(answer_id),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (coment_id);
```

Comment: how should we know without seeing your table structure?

Comment: Your table structure doesn't support nested comments.. so to fetch the comments for a particular question or answer you would only need one query.

Comment: sorry folks! I added the basic structure as I expected.

Comment: @MikeB This is just a basic structure I was thinking of. I wish to find the most practical database structure and corresponding query.

Comment: @Ali I was confused because you mentioned the word nested in your question which implies a parent->child relationship in the database. Providing an answer to such a question relies heavily on the implementation of that structure (will you have left and right fields as well? etc). Maybe you only meant nested visually on the page?

Comment: If the comments are refering to Answers only, the reference should be only one: `answer_id int(11) REFERENCES answers(answer_id)`. Having 2 references, one to Answers and one to Questions seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a Table structure as follows(simplified)

> ```
> Questions Table
> QID | Question
>
> Answers Table
> AID | fQID | Answer
>
> Comments Table
> CID | fAID | comment
> ```

fQID = foreign Key for Questions Table

fAID = foreign key for Answers table

Following query will select all the comments for a particular question

```
select comment from question join answers on QUI=fQUID join comments on AID=fAID where QID='$questionID'
```

Following query will select comments accourding to the Answer ID

```
select aid, answer, comment from question join answers on QUI=fQUID join comments on AID=fAID where AID='$answerID'
```

Edit:

For Nesting comments under answers, use something like this (you will need to modify this, this is very rough)

```
$sql = 'select comment, cid, aid, answer from question join answers on QUI=fQUID left join comments on AID=fAID where QID='$questionID' order by AID';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<div>" . $row['answer'];
$current = $row['aid'];
do{
  if($current != $row['aid']){
    print "</div>\n<div>" . $row['answer'];
    $current = $row['id'];
  }

  $current = $row['aid'];
  if($row['cid'] != null){
    print "<div>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>";
  }
}while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

print "</div>";
```

Comment: well, but how to nest comments under each answer. In this case, I need to execute a query for each answer.

Comment: @Ali I don't understand your concern. Do you wish to NOT have to execute an extra query to fetch the answer's comments?

Comment: @MikeB There can be tens of answers, it is not reasonable to increase the number of mysql queries in this manner (IMHO of course).

Comment: So you want to get the question, answer, and comments all in one query? That wasn't apparent to me from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way and most performant

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
post_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
parent_id int(11) REFERENCES posts(post_id),
title varchar(255),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (post_id);


CREATE TABLE comments (
coment_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id int(11) REFERENCES posts(post_id),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (coment_id);
```

The question posts will have a NULL parent_id. This will be the simplest and most flexible design.

Here is a sample query to load a page.

```
select * from posts where post_id = 9 or parent_id = 9
```

> My question is how to list comments nested under its corresponding
>   answer? I am dealing with the PHP while loop to list answers and
>   sub-lists of comments.

Simple, when you are looping though the posts - filter the comments according to the current post id

---

Now if you want this really easy you can put the comments in the posts table as well

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
post_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
parent_id int(11) REFERENCES posts(post_id),
is_comment bit(1),
title varchar(255),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (post_id);
```

**Notice:** is_comment column

here is how to query a page:

```
select * from posts where post_id = 9 or parent_id = 9 or parent_id IN (select post_id from posts where parent_id = 9)
```

Sorry, i am not a mysql guy